# How is the UML notation in a Design Class Diagram demonstrated to associate a library or separate namespace with a class?

Tags: package, uml, class-diagram

Suppose my following Design Class Diagram:
[image]

I want to demonstrate some of my classes, let's say `Program`, utilizes the `«package» Library` class, which is located in a seperate solution and namespace and referenced through a project dependency. It is important for the overall functionality of the program.

How would I go about doing this? Is the «package» notation correct?

Comment: Sounds like you would use `Component`  here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that one class uses another? I guess a `usage` is the element you need. It is shown with a dashed arrow labeled `«use»`, pointing from the using class to the used class.

Additional note: You defined a stereotype `«package»`. While this is allowed, it might be confusing, since there is a model element of the same name. Maybe, you wanted to show a package called `Library`. The notation would be a rectangle with a tab. Packages can't have operations. You would need to define a class owned by the package that defines the operations. Alternatively, you could define `FunctionBehaviors`. They can be owned by a package and are the correct way to model functions for a non object oriented programming language.

Comment: Cheithauer Thanks for the answer. My professor advised us to use a Package Diagram to illustrate the use and combination of different namespaces across classes - in general it seems to be more of a design aspect rather than there being an absolute or theoretically correct way to do it